# How to set `opt.narenas` for jemalloc in code?

Tags: memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation, jemalloc

Except of the ways of  `ln -s 'narenas:xxx' /etc/malloc.conf` and `export MALLOC_CONF=narenas:xxx`, I want to set narenas in my code. I use `mallcnt` like this:

```
unsigned new_arena_num = 64;
size_t sz = sizeof(new_arena_num);
int res = mallctl("arenas.narenas", NULL, NULL, &new_arena_num, sz);
```

However, `res != 0` and failed. What's wrong ?

Comment: `mallctl("opt.narenas", NULL, NULL, &new_narenas, sizeof(sz))` also not   worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`narenas` cannot be written.

The jemalloc documentation (http://jemalloc.net/jemalloc.3.html) states the option as follows:
`opt.narenas (unsigned) r-`

The read write flags (in this case `r-`) indicate that this value can only be read, not written. `background_threads` on the other hand has `rw` flags.